# merge multiple PDF's using PyPDF2 module using for loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, pdf, pdf-generation, pypdf

I am new to python,trying to merge multiple pdf's passed as arguments to a single pdf with PyPDF2 module but i am getting a empty pdf file as result
, my code is below

```
import os,sys,PyPDF2

pdf_write_object=PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

for i in sys.argv[1:]:
 file_object=open(i,'rb')
 pdf_read_object=PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file_object)
 print('processing file : '+ i + 'number of pages : ' +  str(pdf_read_object.numPages))
 for page in range(pdf_read_object.numPages):
  pdf_write_object.addPage(pdf_read_object.getPage(page))
 file_object.close() 

final_file_object=open('final_PyPDF2.pdf','wb')
pdf_write_object.write(final_file_object)
final_file_object.close()
```

tried using with statement also still the same result

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os,sys,PyPDF2

pdf_write_object=PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

for i in sys.argv[1:]:
 with open(i,'rb') as file_object:
  pdf_read_object=PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file_object)
  print('processing file : '+ i + 'number of pages : ' +  str(pdf_read_object.numPages))
  for page in range(pdf_read_object.numPages):
   pdf_write_object.addPage(pdf_read_object.getPage(page))

final_file_object=open('final_PyPDF2.pdf','wb')
pdf_write_object.write(final_file_object)
final_file_object.close()
```

although using the above method on python terminal on individual files works just as fine, i am missing something in the for loop , can someone please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't open the file to read. `PdfFileReader()` can do it automagically and the code will work:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import PyPDF2

pdf_write_object = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

for i in sys.argv[1:]:
    pdf_read_object = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(i)
    print('processing file : '+ i + 'number of pages : ' +  str(pdf_read_object.numPages))
    for page in range(pdf_read_object.numPages):
        pdf_write_object.addPage(pdf_read_object.getPage(page))

final_file_object = open('final_PyPDF2.pdf', 'wb')
pdf_write_object.write(final_file_object)
final_file_object.close()
```

Comment: that works thanks,  
meanwhile i had figured  removing `file_object.close()` from my first method also gives proper final file but was not sure how my program would work with large pdf's without running out of resource limits 
now your method seems to be better Thanks again.